# wp_enqueue_script / wp_register_script - Which I am not understanding in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Sorry if this question is longwinded. I am trying to be specific.

I am developing a WordPress page with content. I am developing my own theme for it from scratch. On the front page, I want a slideshow with various images.

I am developing my WordPress site locally with WAMP.

I have tried to make this slideshow work in two ways. The first way works, but I don't think this is the correct way to do it.

Method 1:

I include the html for the slideshow in my front-page.php file, and then I include the JavaScript right below it. This works, the slideshow works, everything is awesome. Sadly I don't think this is the correct way.

HOWEVER:

I have done a lot of reading about wp_enqueue_scripts(); and the correct way for JavaScript to be included in WordPress templates. From this, I have gathered that my JavaScript should be in a separate .js file. Then, in my functions.php file, I should register the JavaScript file with a unique name and call it using the wp_enqueue_scripts(); function. If I want to only load the JavaScript on certain pages, I can use conditional logic for that. By default the JavaScript will load in the header of the site. I have read all the articles google search gave me, as well as watched a bunch of videos. It seems that opinions differ slightly on exactly where in the functions.php file to include this, as well as whether it is necessary to call in the JavaScript file separately once it has been registered in functions.

(*sidenote: I understand we also include our CSS this way, with the wp_enqueue_style() function which lives in the functions.php file. I have not had problems with this and my CSS loads fine.*)

If I successfully enqueue my JavaScript this way, I should be able to put the html for my slideshow into the actual WordPress content management system, by including it as page content there. This would be ideal because then I could change and add images from my WordPress dashboard if I needed to. I'm concluding this is much more logical than hard-coding it into my front-page.php file itself.

The only problem is that I can't seem to do this correctly. My slides show up and my CSS shows up, but the JavaScript clearly does not load because there is no slide show functionality and the elements merely all show up on the page, one below the other. I will try to include here as comprehensively and understandably as I can, the various methods I have tried in my functions.php file:

Fail Method 1 is to include this in the functions.php file:*(side note:the wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri()); section of this code works, I've just included it as reference for you to see where in the functions.php file I'm currently including the failed attempt )*

```
<?php

  function GHDCustom_resources () {

    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());

        wp_register_script('ghd-frontpageslideshow', get_template_directory_uri() . '/ghd-js/ghd-frontpageslideshow.js', 'array()', 'false', 'true'); 
  }

{ add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'GHDCustom_resources');

}


?>
```

Fail Method 2 is to keep the functions.php file as shown above, but then to add the following to header.php in the head section: (literally nothing changes.)

```
<?php wp_head(); 
      wp_enqueue_scripts('ghd-frontpageslideshow')
?>
```

Because I have destroyed so many prior attempts, it is difficult for me to iterate every single attempt which did not work. Right now, my brain is too tired to try and recreate each scenario. But the bottom line is that there is clearly something I am missing and not understanding. Any help with what that may be, will be GREATLY appreciated. I have been sitting on this problem for a couple of days. I hope that my question is at least somewhat coherent. If my question is unclear and I need to supply more information or snippets of code, please let me know and I will do so.

Below is the JavaScript for the slideshow as well as the html markup. Like I said, this works if I just include all of it in my front-page.php file as is.

```js
  <script>
                          var slideIndex = 1;
                          showSlides(slideIndex);

                          function plusSlides(n) {
                            showSlides(slideIndex += n);
                          }

                          function currentSlide(n) {
                            showSlides(slideIndex = n);
                          }

                          function showSlides(n) {
                            var i;
                            var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
                            var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
                            if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
                            if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length} ;
                            for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                              slides[i].style.display = "none";
                            }
                            for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                              dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
                            }
                            slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
                            dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
                          }
                    </script>
```

```html
  <!--front-page-image-slideshow-->

                      <div class="frontpage-slideshow-container">
                        <div class="mySlides fade">
                          <img src="/ghd-grafix/shortycakes-logo.png" style="width: 100%">
                          <div class="text"><p>Logo for Small Bakery Business</p></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mySlides fade">
                          <img src="/ghd-grafix/tourmaline-image.png" style="width: 100%">
                          <div class="text"><p>Website Banner for Client: CUBE</p></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mySlides fade">
                          <img src="/ghd-grafix/client-icon-set.png" style="width: 100%">
                          <div class="text"><p>Icon Set for Client: CUBE</p></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mySlides fade">
                          <img src="/ghd-grafix/run-the-race-cross-and-foot.png" style="width: 100%">
                          <div class="text"><p>Logo for Prayer Campaign</p></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="mySlides fade">
                          <img src="/ghd-grafix/suaveaudio-visualasset.png" style="width: 100%">
                          <div class="text"><p>Logo design and Visual Asset for Audio Visual Company</p></div>
                        </div>


                        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
                      </div>
                    </br>

                    <div style="text-align:center">
                      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
                      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
                      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
                      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
                      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your theme, in `functions.php` do it like this:

```
<?php 

define( 'TEMPPATH', get_template_directory_uri() );
define( 'THEME_VERSION', '1.0.0' );

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'yourtheme_theme_setup' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'yourtheme_theme_setup' ) ) {
    function yourtheme_theme_setup() {
        //actions go here
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'yourtheme_frontend_scripts' );
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'yourtheme_frontend_scripts' ) ) {
    function yourtheme_frontend_scripts() {

        if (is_home()) { // will load only on home
            wp_enqueue_script( 'slick_js', TEMPPATH.'/ghd-js/ghd-frontpageslideshow.js', array( 'jquery' ), THEME_VERSION, true );
        }
        // will load anywhere. Put your scripts and styles here using enqueue functions - you can add more conditionals here...
    }
}
```

This should load your script on your home page only. Notice the `jquery` dependency.

Read more:

[wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

[wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)

Also: [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=enquing%20scripts%20the%20right%20way&oq=enquing%20scripts%20the%20right%20way&aqs=chrome..69i57.6189j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=enqueuing%20scripts%20the%20right%20way&tbs=qdr:y)